# Is there a theoretical limit for energy density?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, energy, particle-physics

How much energy can be added to a small volume of space? Perhaps like the focal point of a very high power femtosecond laser for a short time, or are there other examples like the insides of neutron stars that might be the highest possible energy density? Is there any fundamental limit?

Comment: Even prior to formation of black holes very strong radiation/fields facilitate creation of virtual particles thus loosing energy. So the practical limit is somewhat lower, as determined by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_limit

Comment: @oakad Thanks good link!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a limit to how much energy that can be contained in a finite volume, after which the energy density becomes so high that the region collapses into a [black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole).

We also know that matter and energy are equivalent according to the Einstein equation $$E=mc^2\tag1$$ So if we can determine the greatest amount of matter that can fit into a volume just before it collapses into a black hole, the corresponding energy should also indicate the greatest energy confined in the volume just before it becomes a black hole.

The maximum amount of matter, mass $M$, that can be contained in a given volume before it collapses into a black hole, is given by the [Schwarzschild radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius) $$r_s=\frac{2GM}{c^2}\tag2$$ Using (1) we can then write $$M=\frac{E}{c^2}$$ so that equation (2) becomes $$r_s=\frac{2GE}{c^4}$$ or $$E=\frac{r_sc^4}{2G}$$

Note that this is still energy, and to get to energy *density* we need to define the volume which is of course $$V=\frac 43 \pi r_s^3$$ so that the energy density is $$\epsilon =\frac{3c^4}{8\pi Gr_s^2}$$

This computation is based on not much more than the equivalence of matter and energy. It represents a bound on the maximum amount of matter, and therefore energy, in a *spherical* volume of radius $r_s$ before the volume  containing the matter collapses into a singularity, which of course has no properly defined volume.

Comment: It may be helpful to add the numerical value of that constant in front of the 1/r^2 in some common unit(s), eg J/cm and whatever would be used for this in imperial units.

Comment: Thanks, would this also be true for electromagnetic fields, if matter wasn’t present?

Comment: yet, the Schwartzschild radious can't be associated easily to density, as the volume of a sphere in the interior of the BH is NOT $\frac{4\pi r_s^3}{3}$,  distances inside a massive body depend on the distribution of matter... so, the association you make between density and the Schwartzschild radious is incorrect

Comment: @UVphoton Assuming spherical symmetry and asymptotic flatness (these are good assumptions for a highly compressed isolated system), yes, this numerical bound holds regardless of the form the energy takes, even if some is present in an extended electric field (as in the Reissner-Nordstrom solution), provided you make the iffy identification of the black hole's "volume". Outside of asymptotic flatness, one can violate the bound given here: indeed, *every* nontrivial FLRW metric violates this bound at *each* cosmological time beyond some length scale.

Comment: I think the cosmological point is an important caveat to make in this answer. This is not at all a fundamental upper bound to the energy density that can be contained within a given radius. Since the given density goes to zero as $r_s \to \infty$, and since the observable universe looks quite homogeneous on large scales (i.e., on large scales it has constant energy density in the standard spatial slices of cosmology), this bound is always violated on a sufficiently large scale. And the farther back in the universe's history we go, the smaller the violation scale, going to zero at the big bang.

Comment: But this calculation suggests that for any energy density one would like to reach one simply has to choose a sufficiently small total mass/Schwarzschild radius, and one would be fine, right? No black hole created - in theory... ;)

Comment: @jawheele Your point about universal expansion is indeed a good one. I will edit the answer as soon as I have some time, though I assumed that particular point was implicitly understood  in my answer.

Comment: Isn't this distinction between "mass" and "energy" irrelevant or misleading anyway? Typically, we make this distinction if we want to oppose particles with rest mass to photons, e.g. before and after a pair annihilation. But at these high energy densities, I suppose, one would have a lot of spontaneous *pair creation* anyway, that is, at least some of the energy would take the form of particles with rest mass. And to an observer, the energy dense volume inside a black box would simply have the corresponding mass in any case.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I think that gets at the heart of what I was wondering about. As well as what jawheele pointed out. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure about this answer? I am under the impression there is no limit, since if there were one, the universe would have collapsed into a black hole shortly after the Big Bang.

Answer (score 7):

This limit is given by the [Bekenstein Bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound). It is proportional to the surface area of the surface enclosing a given volume. Exceeding this bound would create a black hole.

Comment: The Bekenstein bound is technically an upper limit on the entropy in a region. Also, please do not use mobile device friendly links. I've edited the link to the desktop kind. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, interesting wikipedia article.